# error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'float *' and 'float *')

Tags: c

can someone help me out? i the only thing wrong is i cant add cost1,cost2, and cost3 up at the end to print out my total from the three items. i get the above error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char name1[100];
char name2[100];
char name3[100];
char price1[100];
char price2[100];
char price3[100];
float cost1[100];
float cost2[100];
float cost3[100];
float total[300];

int main()
{
printf("Welcome to the UT super mart*-*-\n");
printf("Enter the name of your item 1: ");
fgets(name1, sizeof(name1), stdin);
printf("Enter the price of %s: ", name1);
fgets(price1, sizeof(price1), stdin);
sscanf(price1, "%f", &cost1);

printf("Enter the name of your item 2: ");
fgets(name2, sizeof(name2), stdin);
printf("Enter the price of %s: ", name2);
fgets(price2, sizeof(price2), stdin);
sscanf(price2, "%f", &cost2);

printf("Enter the name of your item 3: ");
fgets(name3, sizeof(name3), stdin);
printf("Enter the price of %s: ", name3);
fgets(price3, sizeof(price3), stdin);
sscanf(price3, "%f", &cost3);

total=cost1+cost2+cost3; /*this is what causes the error*/
printf("Your total is: %f\nThank you for shopping at the UT super mart.", total);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: please keep in mind im a beginner

Comment: Hi Derek, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is about the `C` language, not `C#` as tagged.  These are quite different languages, so please be careful to tag correctly.  That said, cjds has posted an answer that should explain the problem.

Comment: my bad, i am very very new to programming

Comment: It helps you to get better answers as well as people tend to monitor the areas they are most interested in, and `C#` people aren't necessarily going to give you the best answers to a `C` problem. Hope you find your answer.

Comment: I've rolled back your most recent edit. You changed the code in your question to correct the problem you're asking about. That invalidates any answers and makes the question useless. Please don't do that.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code. indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and allows for many indent levels across the page.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is declaring the cost variables as arrays. Not needed.

```
float cost1[100];
float cost2[100];
float cost3[100];
float total[300];
```

should be

```
float cost1;
float cost2;
float cost3;
float total;
```